# Process unstructured data into structured data to build predictive model?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am new to Hadoop, i have unstructured data files, need to convert into structed data is that possible in mapreduce?if not which is the best practice

```
file1.txt


Message-ID: <5482922.1075855813971.JavaMail.evans@thyme>

Date: Thu, 26 Oct 2000 09:21:00 -0700 (PDT)

From: ted.bland@enron.com

To: janet.dietrich@enron.com, wes.colwell@enron.com, sally.beck@enron.com, 
    kevin.presto@enron.com, thomas.martin@enron.com, 
    hunter.shively@enron.com, scott.neal@enron.com, w.duran@enron.com, 
    jeff.donahue@enron.com, brian.redmond@enron.com

Subject: Super Saturday Interviewers for October 28, 2000



file2.txt

Message-ID: <12142333.1075855814153.JavaMail.evans@thyme>

Date: Tue, 24 Oct 2000 14:12:00 -0700 (PDT)

From: enron.announcements@enron.com

To: ena.employees@enron.com

Subject: Associate/Analyst Super Saturday Participation - ADDITIONAL REQUEST


file1.txt and file2.txt are two file, i want the output like

Message-ID      Date        From        To      Subject

respective values as like table. Is that possible in Mapreduce?
```

Comment: start from here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop API provides an [InputFormat](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/InputFormat.html) interface to define how your input data should be translated into collection of key-value pairs.

There are a number of built-in input formats already (see the list of implementing classes in the documentation), but they are very general purpose and are better suited for structured data. For example, [TextInputFormat](http://TextInputFormat.html) assumes that each individual line is a separate record and produces key-value pairs where keys are line numbers and values are the line of text.

For unstructured data you'll have to define your own custom input format class. Here's a [link](https://shrikantbang.wordpress.com/2013/10/22/hadoop-custom-input-format/) to a short tutorial on how to do that.

On a side note, consider using [Apache Spark](http://spark.apache.org/), which has everything that Hadoop has to offer and also a very useful [machine learning library](http://spark.apache.org/mllib/) that you can use to build models.